# Supplements for me

Tags: supplements

I'm 51, 6', 205 lbs and train 4-5 days a week (5/3/1 program). I'm currently taking: a Multi (GNC for old men), D3, Calcium/Magnisum/Zinc and Fish Oil and Fiber.  I also try to get to about 130-150 grams protein a day.  I'm feeling good, good recovery BUT **want to see if there's any changes I can make to improve overall stamina/strength.**

Comment: What is your current workout routine like and the rest of your diet? We need a little more information to best help you.

Comment: I'm on  month 10 of 5/3/1 - squating 300 lbs, deadlifting 415 lbs, benching 240 lbs and pressing 150 lbs (all for reps).  Mostly weight training, some kettlebell, etc. when the mood hits me.

Comment: In my opinion supplements don't really increase stamina and strength, I would credit that to your weightlifting routine. Do you have a post workout protein shake? If so, what is it? You still haven't given a lot of information. Such as -  are you looking for *supplements* to increase strength and stamina? Are you considering switching up your routine or is this just about supplements?

Comment: Pre/Post I take Whey (about 30 grams) via a shake and/or mixing with food.  I'm not looking to change my routine, I'm looking to improve my supplements that I'm taking to support my routine

Comment: I really find it hard to advise someone which supplements he needs or is missing, especially without knowing your diet. That's why I voted to close this question. It might be better to ask which nutrients are needed to increase stamina and strength, although I think that stamina and strength might deserve a question on its own. And I am still not sure how to not make it a nutrition question then …

Answer (score 2):

**Carbs**

---

In my opinion the importance of carbs (post workout) is generally overlooked. If you read [this article](http://sportsmedicine.about.com/cs/nutrition/a/aa081403.htm) and many others like it, it explains that combining carbohydrates and protein (in a 4:1 ratio) within 30 minutes of exercising is very important. Why?

```
"Research also shows that combining protein with carbohydrate within thirty minutes of
exercise nearly doubles the insulin response, which results in more stored glycogen."
```

I think adding a combination of protein and carbs to your post workout shake would greatly benefit you and improve recovery.

Recommended Supplements -

- [NOW - Carbo Gain](http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/now/carbo.html) (Mix w/ whey)
- Or just drink some fruit juice

**Casein**

---

Casein can help refuel your body when you go for long periods without food (i.e. when you are sleeping).

Recommended Supplements -

- [ON 100% Casein](http://www.optimumnutrition.com/products/100-casein-protein-p-219.html)

**[Creatine](http://www.menshealth.com/nutrition/creatine-side-effects-what-it-what-it-does)**

---

Of course, creatine is always an option. It is one of the most widely used supplements and there is plenty of research out there confirming its benefits for improving recovery, thus allowing you to complete more reps to improve strength. You should definitely do a lot of research before considering creatine though because there is a lot of information needed before taking it. I'd recommend reading a "beginner's guide" or something similar. Something like [this](http://www.schwarzenegger.com/fitness/post/creatine-how-much-should-you-be-taking).

Recommended Supplements -

- [ON Micronized Creatine Monohydrate (powder)](http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/crea.html)